# How can I view the body data of an HTTP request in a Firebase Functions JS?

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase, google-cloud-functions

"I'm trying to view the body data in a Firebase Functions POST request, but the console always returns "undefined" in the Firebase function logs!

Question: How can I view the body data in a Firebase function to use it?

Request :
[image]

Here My Code :

```
exports.test = functions.https.onRequest(async (req, res) => {
 const id = req.body.id

});
```

I allready used but not working :

```
  req.on('data', (chunk) => {
    // The chunk is a Buffer object containing a chunk of the request body data
    body += chunk;
  }).on('end', () => {
    // The request body data has been fully received, and the `body` variable contains the complete request body
  });
```

i should to get id from body.id

Comment: Please add the request that you are calling the function with, including any relevant headers.

Comment: This [other answer thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64746618/3068190) may also be of use.

Comment: updated. I still dont know

Comment: Voting to reopen as OP is using a Content Type of `multipart/form-data` not `application/json`.

Comment: Khalifa, in the mean time, you should add `busboy` as a dependency to your project and then feed it `req.rawBody`. This is because `multipart/form-data` is not one of the content types handled automatically by the [Functions Framework](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/http-events#read_values_from_the_request). There are a number of examples using it with Cloud Functions here on SO. What data is your function uploading? (images, videos, text, etc.)

Comment: can you take a look at mu answer ?

Comment: I made the mistake to not set the proper content type on the request

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68040185/20239914) thread’s answer you should use `Content-Type` and make it to "application/json"
as only then your body will be accessible like as shown in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64746618/20239914)

Also you can check out [Read values from the request](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/http-events#read_values_from_the_request) which explains the need of `application/json` on `Content Type`.

If you check the firebase functions logs you can see there is no incoming body received from the request and because of that your body content’s are undefined.

There is also a possibility that the `req.body` property in a Firebase Functions is not properly formatted or if it is not properly parsed by the Function, so you can force it to parse using `JSON.parse(req.body);` to parse the request body.
So the updated code will something look like:

```
exports.test = functions.https.onRequest(async (req, res) => {
  const body = JSON.parse(req.body);
  const id = body.id;
  // ...
});
```

OR

> You can use the body parser middleware and force [parse the body as JSON](https://www.npmjs.com/package/body-parser#bodyparserjsonoptions:%7E:text=to%20true.-,type,-The%20type%20option) as shown in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72459830/20239914)

Comment: Contacting Firebase Support for this problem isn't suitable. My mention of contacting them on [the linked answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69733262/20239914) was because the built-in Framework was crashing without letting the user's code have the opportunity to handle the error if the body could not be parsed by the built-in JSON parser.

Comment: @samthecodingman Edited the answer can you have a look at it again ?

Answer (score 0):

**req.body** can be used if the request body type is application/json or application/x-www-form-urlencoded otherwise use **req.rawBody**

Comment: how to use req.rawbody in js ?